# Add padding to last ListView item in WinForms

Tags: c#, winforms, listview

How can I add some extra space between the last item in a listview and the bottom of the control? I don't want to add an empty item to the bottom of the list.

Comment: Maybe this will help ? http://qdevblog.blogspot.nl/2011/11/c-listview-item-spacing.html

Comment: When you add a new item to the ListView you can just add to the upper bounds of the item such as: myListViewItem.Bounds.Top += marginAmt; You can place this within the ControlAdded event of the ListView.

Comment: What View mode do you use?

Comment: @Ckrempp: This i s Winforms. The Bounds can't be changed and adding an Item doesn't invoke ControlAdded..

Comment: @Sybren: Intersting, but only works for the LV as a whole, not individual Items.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can't do this directly. Unfortunately the styling options of `ListView` are rather limited.

Unless you go for owner-drawing it.. Which is powerful and not very hard. But even there I doubt that the `Items` can have different `Heights`..

But there is a simple trick you can use:

Remove the LV's borders and place it inside a `Panel` with appropriate borders. `Dock` it there to `Fill` the Panel and give the Panel a `Padding` of maybe (0;0;0,10) and voila, the will always be a `Padding` of 10 pixels that looks as if it belongs to the `ListView`..

Instead of using the Designer, you could put these lines in the `Form.Load` to make it work on startup:

```
Panel P = new Panel();
P.BackColor = listView1.BackColor;
P.Location = listView1.Location;
P.Size = listView1.Size;
P.Padding = new System.Windows.Forms.Padding(0,0,0,10);
P.BorderStyle = listView1.BorderStyle;
listView1.BorderStyle = BorderStyle.None;
listView1.Parent = P;
listView1.Dock = DockStyle.Fill;
this.Controls.Add(P);
```

Answer (score 0):

Use item.IndentCount

[Microsoft ListViewItem property IndentCount](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.listviewitem.indentcount?view=netframework-4.7)

[image]Count][2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gPOEC.png)